# Prove square root inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Consider: $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$, prove $$\sqrt{4a+1}+\sqrt{4b+1}+\sqrt{4c+1}\leq \sqrt{21}. $$

It is supposed to be solved using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (multiplying by $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $(1\cdot\sqrt{4a+1}+1\cdot\sqrt{4b+1}+1\cdot\sqrt{4c+1})^2 \le (1^2+1^2+1^2)(.....).$. Can you finish it ?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks.

Comment: @MCuadros: My pleasure.